# Attempting to validate a custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I'm struggling with a particular case for validation.  I have to do cross-field validation with what is essentially a more complicated multi-select directive.  The problem is that this is a very general directive and will not necessarily need validation in every case nor will it need the same validation.

*simplifiedSelect.tpl.html*

```
<select name="vm.name" ng-options='p in data' ng-model='vm.model'>
```

*simplifiedSelect.js*

```
(function() {
    angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('simplifiedSelect', simplifiedSelect)
function simplifiedSelect(){
    var directive = {
        restrict='E',
        scope:{
           secondVar:'='
        },
        controller:Controller,
        controllerAs:'vm',
        templateUrl: '/simplifiedSelect.tpl.html'
     }
     Controller.$inject('$scope')
     function Controller($scope) {
         //do stuff
     }
 }());
```

Every example that I have seen seems to require that the validation directives are attached directly to the input, not to the directive itself, and attempting to attach the validation to the directive led to having no result, even when I attached and required ngModel to the outer directive.  I have been able to get a basic custom validation to work on another field, but this is just beyond me.